# Changing Kendo UI Grid Row Font Color causing strange selected CSS display issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Using Kendo UI Grid, I am getting strange selected item styling issues after adding a simple CSS class to each TD within a row via jQuery, see my fiddle:

The latest version of Kendo UI Fiddle (v2014.1.318) demonstrates the bug:
http://jsfiddle.net/sweetog/63j8T/1/

This fiddle is referencing v2013.1.514, and the bug is not there:
http://jsfiddle.net/sweetog/AHN8S/1/

After changing the font color to red and selecting the row again, the k-state-selected class acts strangely and no longer highlights the entire row when clicked but only intermittently:

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var dataSource;
  var kendoCheckedIds = {};

  dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
      read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
    },
    pageSize: 10
  });

  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    pageable: {
      refresh: true,
      pageSizes: true,
      buttonCount: 5
    },
    columns: [{template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />", width: 30},
      {
        field: "ContactName",
        title: "Contact Name",
        width: 200
      }, {
        field: "ContactTitle",
        title: "Contact Title",
        width: 250
      }, {
        field: "CompanyName",
        title: "Company Name"
      }, {
        field: "Country",
        width: 150
      }]
  })
    .data("kendoGrid")
    .table.on("click", ".checkbox", selectKendoGridRow);

  function selectKendoGridRow() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      row = $(this).closest("tr"),
      grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid"),
      dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);

    if (checked) {
      //-select the row
      kendoCheckedIds[dataItem.uid] = checked;
      grid.select(row); // select the item  
      //row.addClass("k-state-selected");
    } else {
      //-remove selection
      delete kendoCheckedIds[dataItem.uid];
      //row.removeClass("k-state-selected");
      grid.clearSelection(row);
    }
  }

  $('#btnMarkRed').click(function () {
    var view = dataSource.view();
    var colorClass = 'color-red';
    var grid = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid");

    for (var i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
      if (kendoCheckedIds[view[i].uid]) {
        var row = $("#grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid='" + view[i].uid + "']");
        row.find(".checkbox").prop('checked', false);
        $.each(row.find('td'), function (index, element) {
          $(element).toggleClass(colorClass);
        });
        //row.removeClass(otherColorClass).toggleClass(colorClass);
      }
    }

    grid.clearSelection();
    kendoCheckedIds = {};
  });
});
```

**HTML**
Mark Checked Items Color Red

```
<div id="grid" style="height: 365px"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
 td.color-red
    {
        color: red !important;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Wow. I've been playing with it a bit and this is a really weird one. If we assume that it's not a CSS/Browser bug, than the most likely thing is that there is something inside the Kendo JS libraries where the `click` action on that row is concerned that glitches when the style is changed. I tried modifying it so that the class was on the TR also, but with the same result.

Comment: Ya I had it on the TR originally too because it was so weird and switched to the TDs just to see if it made a difference

Comment: Just at a loss, using an older version of Kendo UI CSS fixed this issue but I need to use the latest version, check out my updated question I have added another fiddle that references an older version of Kendo UI and you can see it works